# How do I select records where multiple values of different columns have not been exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been looking for a solution for the below question, sadly to no avail. 
This is for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on Microsoft SQL Server.

The database looks more or less like this:

```
ID    LegID   TripID     
1     0       0  
1     0       1  
1     1       0  
2     0       0  
2     1       0 
2     2       0 
2     2       1  
3     0       0 
3     0       1 
3     0       2
```

I'm looking for a result where all records will selected be for the ID's where the legID does not exceed 1 and the TripID does not exceed 1. The result then should be:

```
ID    LegID   TripID     
1     0       0  
1     0       1  
1     1       0
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Derived table (subquery) to get all the `id` values matching your requirements, utilizing conditional aggregation based filtering. And, then join back to the main table to get all the rows for those `id` value(s).

```
SELECT 
  t1.* 
FROM 
  your_table_name t1 
JOIN (SELECT ID
      FROM your_table_name 
      GROUP BY ID 
      HAVING MAX(LegID) <= 1 
         AND MAX(TripID) <= 1) t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

One method use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        (t2.LegId > 1 or t2.TripId > 1)
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(id, legid, tripid)`.

You could also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(legid) over (partition by id) as max_legid,
             max(tripid) over (partition by id) as max_tripid
      from t
     ) t
where max_legid <= 1 and max_tripid <= 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the "not exists" working, the "windows functions" give some errors (line 4 and 5, Invalid column name 'id'.). Tried to fix these but couldn't get it working. I found that the solution by Madhur Bhaiya worked faster.

Comment: @JorritK . . . `id` is in your data, so it should work.  I'm surprised that the `GROUP BY` method is faster than the `NOT EXISTS`.  If you have the specified index, is it still faster?

Comment: Fixed the ID, works now thanks! Also reran the queries while forcing them to use the specific table index rather than the default index but performance remains the same.